# Python Sql Using as Variable

Tags: python, sql

I am using pyodbc connection and i wrote this code;

```
database="Salih"

cnxn=pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';Trusted_Connection='+trusted) 


curs = cnxn.cursor()
dt=curs.execute("select top 100* from [Salih].[tableau].[Results]" )
column_names = [i[0] for i in curs.description]
dt = curs.fetchall()
```

I'm trying to change the database part after from into as variable.
Instead of this;

```
   dt=curs.execute("select top 100* from [Salih].[tableau].[Results]" )
```

This should be;

```
   dt=curs.execute("select top 100* from [str(database)].[tableau].[Results]" )
```

Could you please help me about this?

Comment: Are Salih, tableau, Results variable or indexes in a dict ? please share the elements that we see and that are missing? are they the names of your table ? With the  [ ] quite strange, And is the version you show working ?

Comment: Try: `dt=curs.execute("select top 100* from [" + database + "].[tableau].[Results]" )` No need to `str()` the `database` name, as it is already a string.

Comment: I'd say that you don't need the Salih prefix if you're in the Salih DB, except you decide to call table with prefix Salih in the Salih DB^^